# How to get a session variable work in java script function?

Tags: php, session

It may look like a stupid question, but I went through various pages since 2 days, and didn't get to a solution by myself.
So I made a session variable like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['currentpage']="home";
?>
```

(I checked, it does make the variable and assign it right.)

Then I tried to use it as a parameter here:

`<body onload="changepage($_SESSION['currentpage'])">`

It doesn't pass the variable. I tried to put it into directly the function, like not as a parameter, but inside it, doesn't work either.
I am seriously missing something here I bet. Can someone please help out?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the PHP tags:

```
<body onload="changepage('<?php echo $_SESSION['currentpage']; ?>')">
```

Comment: Or the shorter version, if your php.ini allows these: `<?=$_SESSION['currentpage']; ?>`

Comment: @StefanCandan Yeah, sure. That just comes down to personal preference, both works.

Comment: Oh my god. Thanks a lot, works now. Didn't know how to make it phpish there..:)

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onload="changepage($_SESSION['currentpage'])">
```

Should be

```
<body onload="changepage('<?php echo $_SESSION['currentpage'];?>')">
```